# transform-style:preserve-3d and opacity in latest google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, opacity

I only get this in the latest google chrome as well as chrome canary (the beta chrome).

Instead of the image displaying with a 75% opacity, all I see is the black background color that I set on the image.

This appears to be because I set the transform-style to "preserve-3d". Is this a known bug? Is there any way I can combine transform-style and still use opacity?

http://jsfiddle.net/RJQ3S/

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I have no idea what's happening here - can't find any info about known bug - but i seems to be fixed if you add opacity to the second div:

http://jsfiddle.net/RJQ3S/3/

Comment: Perfect solution thanks - I had to add prefix version 

-webkit-opacity: 0.99;
-moz-opacity: 0.99;
filter:alpha(opacity=99);